# connect to subnet via VPN

Tags: internet, debian, vpn, lan, subnet

i have VPN setup which is like this:

```
########### internet  ############## internet  ############   LAN   ############
# macbook # --------> # VPN server #----------># PC A     # -------># PC B     #
#10.8.0.6 #           # 10.8.0.1   #           # 10.8.0.7 #         # 192.168..#
###########           ##############           ############         ############
```

and now i want to access the PC B in the local LAN of PC A ( A is in VPN net ) with my macbook, I can access PC A with my macbook, so VPN works, i just need some way to route the traffic from the macbook over PC A ( i guess ) to reach PC B in the LAN of PC A, i cant add PC B to the vpn net because i dont have (physical) access to it. ( i hope this is not too confusing )
how can i do this?
VPN Server and PC A are running Debian,

any advice is greatly appreciated :),
and sorry for my bad english

Comment: You should add the addresses of `PC A` and `PC B` in the 192.168.. subnet. What local subnet does the macbook use, or is no router involved at the macbook location?

Answer (score 0):

**If you can modify the network on PC A** then you can give it multiple IP addresses. Leave one in the 10.0.0.x range so you can keep communicating with PC A via the VPN server. Add a second IP to the NIC in 192.168.x.x range.

It is likely that you will need to add a route on PC A to indicate that it should use that IP/interface to communicate with PC B. Either via `route add -net` for the whole 192.168.x.x network or `route add -host 192.168.a.b. netmask foo.bar.baz.foo` (etc etc) for a single specific host.

Now you should be able to communicate from PC A to PC B.

If you are allowed to enable routing on PC A then you can also set it up so that you can reach PC B directly from your macbook or VPN server.

You can check this with `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` or enable it with `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Also, the first `internet` between macbook en VPN server probably should be `LAN`.  Routing of 10.x.x.x ranges to the internet quite non traditional. :)

Comment: I would guess PC A can already access PC B. This is why he wrote "LAN" above that connection. Also bot "internet" labels should indicated that the VPN server is on a different site than the macbook and PC A. Of course, there is lots of information missing about IPs and routing.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is not completely defined.
I make this assumption:

- `PC A` is already in the VPN *and* in the 192.168.. subnet.
  So `PC A` can reach `PC B` normally.

The exact addresses of `PC A` and `PC B` in the local subnet are not given, unfortunately.

---

Since you don't have control over `PC B` you have to create a **port forwarding** on `PC A` for every port you want access at PC B.

On debian you should forward ports using `iptables`.
I have a similar setup with a opensuse machine that forwards RDP on `PC B` over the VPN.
This would be on `PC A`.

```
pc_b=192.168...
macbook=10.8.0.6

case "$1" in
'start')
        iptables -F FORWARD
        iptables -t nat -F
        iptables -P FORWARD DROP
        echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

        iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

        # VPN FORWARD of the RDP port (3389)
        iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s $pc_b --sport 3389 -d $macbook -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp -s $pc_b -d $macbook -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d $pc_b --dport 3389 -s $macbook -j ACCEPT

        iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT

        # RDP from VPN
        iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 3389 \
                -j DNAT --to-destination $pc_b
        ;;
'stop')
        iptables -F FORWARD
        iptables -t nat -F
        iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
        echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        ;;
'status')
        iptables -t nat -L PREROUTING
        ;;
esac
```

This script accepts `start`, `stop` and `status` and can be used in rc.d as a run-level script on `PC A`
`tun0` is the VPN interface.

This will disallow any traffic between the `192.168..` subnet and the VPN except for the ports explicitely opened (3389 in this example).
You don't have to disallow all other forwarding, but I would recommend it.

This will also forward access to `10.8.0.7:3389` to `192.168..:3389`.

---

If you don't want to use port forwarding, you have to change the routing on `PC B` somehow.
If you don't have access to `PC B`, then you need to **route the traffic** from the default gateway of `PC B` **to the VPN**.
One possibility is to route traffic for the VPN from the default gateway to `PC A`.

**This only works if you use a different subnet at the location of the macbook than the one used between `PC A` and `PC B`**
If you use some type of router with your macbook you probably also have a 192.168.. subnet there.

For this setup you don't use the previous script.

You still need

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

(same as `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ipforward=1`)

How to setup routing depends on the OS on the default gateway and your macbook.
In general it works like this:

On macbook (route to `PC B`):

```
route add 192.168.. gw 10.8.0.7
```

This only works if there is no 192.168.. local subnet already present for the macbook!

On the default gateway of `PC B` (route to VPN over `PC A`):

```
route add 10.8.0.6 gw 192.168..
```

Of course, since the internal subnet addresses of `PC A` and `PC B` are not given by the question, I can't give the exact routing information either.